# Difference between viewControllers and childViewControlle for UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

```
fileprivate func test() {

        guard let w = self.view.window else {
            print("no window")
            return
        }
        guard let rootvc = w.rootViewController as? UINavigationController else {
            print("no rootvc")
            return
        }

        for vc in rootvc.childViewControllers {
            print("CHILD \(vc)")
        }

        for vc in rootvc.viewControllers {
            print("VC \(vc)")
        }
}
```

the code above shows the same. But whats the difference between `childViewControllers` and `viewControllers` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to documentation:

```
public var childViewControllers: [UIViewController] { get }
```

**childViewControllers:** An array of view controllers that are children of the current view controller. (read-only). This property does not include any presented view controllers. This property is only intended to be read by an implementation of a custom container view controller.

```
var viewControllers: [UIViewController] { get set }
```

**viewControllers:** The view controllers currently on the navigation stack.

**NOTE:** A `ViewController` also have `childViewControllers` property. but `viewControllers` property defined in `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 1):

`ViewControllers` are `The view controllers currently on the navigation stack.` Where `ChildViewControllers` are `An array of view controllers that are children of the current view controller`.

The root view controller is at index 0 in the array, the back view controller is at index n-2, and the top controller is at index n-1, where n is the number of items in the array.
Assigning a new array of view controllers to this property is equivalent to calling the setViewControllers:animated: method with the animated parameter set to false.

`ChildViewControllers` property does not include any presented view controllers. This property is only intended to be read by an implementation of a custom container view controller.

You can easily get description about it by `Alt + Click` on syntax!!